# Clean only selected modules before building linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I have a situation here where I need to build same kernel against different configs. Now I was trying to build the kernel without doing a make clean but this gives me problem. There is possibility that one config has some drivers as built in and other may have same drive as a module.
In my case, I want to avoid make clean to save time! Compiling a fresh kernel takes allot time and since, I've compiled the same kernel before with only few driver/modules changed, I would like to know any alternate option than cleaning the whole kernel.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don’t have to rebuild the complete kernel if you are just working on a few modules. However, if your module requires changes to `.config` then do the steps below everytime to get a module built for a specific `.config`

```
modify/copy the .config as per the requirement into the src dir
make prepare
make scripts
make modules_prepare
make M=drivers/<some driver>
make M=drivers/<some driver> clean
```

Comment: Thanks! Your suggestion will work for sure for one or two modules. But I have four config files. My script copies the config file one by one and does the compilation. The drivers/modules which are changed are plenty. I can't do one by one clean for those. Is there anyway, the make clean command cleans only those drivers/modules for which config has been changed?

Comment: You have a few choices here, put the above steps into a build script and run the script for different config file every time. Alternative, if you are using git/version control, you could just checkout the code into four separate folders and build each with a separate config. There is no way would can provide multiple config at the same time you need to automate this using your build scripts which sounds simple enough.

Answer (score 2):

Lets say you just want to compile wireless module only.
Now its files are under `Linux_kernel/net/wireless` folder

to compile only wireless modules.

```
cd Linux_kernel
make ARCH=arm modules M=$(pwd)/net/wireless/
```

It will generate two modules

> Linux_kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
>
> Linux_kernel/net/wireless/lib80211.ko

Now to clean these module

```
make ARCH=arm modules M=$(pwd)/net/wireless/ clean
```

Comment: Thanks! Your suggestion will work for sure for one or two modules. But I have four config files. My script copies the config file one by one and does the compilation. The drivers/modules which are changed are plenty. I can't do one by one clean for those. Is there anyway, the make clean command cleans only those drivers/modules for which config has been changed?

Comment: First "Thanks" in stackoverflow is a upvote. If you are using multiple .config file then i suggest you to clean all modules each time. Because what you are saying is gona create much messy in kernel compilation.